# Custom Workflow problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-workflow

I have a Vacation Approval Workflow that assigns a task to the supervisor that has a dropdown for approve or reject. The problem is the workflow doesn't always send the correct response email. I ran 7 vacation request and this is the results. Can someone help me with this. This is my first attempt at creating a custom workflow.

[image]

The following are the step in my workflow:

[image]